# ANTLR @header, @parser, superClass option and basic file io (Java)

Tags: java, antlr, superclass

I want to use parser actions with basic file io (Java), e. g. PrintWriter in an ANTLR grammar. Must I use the superClass option or can I use @header? In both cases how can I declare the PrintWriter-object and how must I handle the exceptions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The option `superClass=...` is used to let your `Parser` extend a custom class. So, I don't think that is what you're after.

Everything inside the `@header` section will be placed at the start of your `Parser` class. This is used to import classes:

```java
@header {
  import java.io.PrintWriter;
}
```

Note that `@header {...}` is short for `@parser::header {...}`. You can also define: `@lexer::header {...}` for your lexer.

And inside `@member {...}` (or: `@parser::member {...}`, `@lexer::member {...}`) sections, you can add instance variables and methods that can be used inside either the `Parser` or `Lexer`:

```java
@header {
  import java.io.PrintWriter;
}

@members {
  PrintWriter writer;
}
```

A small demo of a grammar whose parser will write the parsed numbers to a specific writer:

```java
grammar T;

@header {
  import java.io.PrintWriter;
}

@members {
  PrintWriter writer;

  public TParser(TokenStream input, String fileName) {
    super(input);
    try {
      writer = new PrintWriter(fileName);
    } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}

parse
  :  numbers EOF
  ;

numbers
  :  (NUM {
            writer.println("parsed: " + $NUM.text);
            writer.flush();
          }
     )+
  ;

NUM : '0'..'9'+;
WS  : ' ' {skip();};
```

which can be tested with:

```java
import java.io.File;
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String source = "42 500000000 666";
    TLexer lexer = new TLexer(new ANTLRStringStream(source));
    TParser parser = new TParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer), "log.txt");
    parser.parse();
  }
}
```

If you run the class above, a file called `log.txt` has been created containing:

```
parsed: 42
parsed: 500000000
parsed: 666
```

Note that there is a strict order of all these `@...` and `options {...}` etc. instances:

1. `grammar` definition
2. `options` block (no `@` sign!)
3. `tokens` block (no `@` sign!)
4. `@header` block
5. `@members` block

```
grammar T;

options {
  // options here
}

tokens {
  // imaginary tokens here
}

@header  { 
  // ... 
}

@members { 
  // ... 
}
```

---

#### EDIT

> ***ANTLRStarter wrote:***
>
> How can I add code which is executed at the end of the the lexer/parser class?

There's no built-in functionality for such a thing. But you can easily create a custom method `wrapUp()` in your parser:

```
@members {

  // ...

  private void wrapUp() {
    // wrap up your parser in here
  }
}
```

and then automatically call that method from the entry point of your grammar like this:

```
parse
@after {this.wrapUp();}
  :  numbers EOF
  ;
```

Any code placed in the `@after {...}` block of a rule is executed when everything in the rule is properly matched.

Comment: Bart, you are my hero again. Many thanks for all your efforts! I have only one additional question: How can I add code which is executed at the end of the the lexer/parser class?

Comment: @BartKiers where did you find the strict order you mentioned? http://www.antlr2.org/doc/options.html states that headers comes before options.

Comment: @Dorothyy, you're linking to v2. For v3, the order is mentioned here: https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Grammars and when reading the grammar of ANTLR3 itself, you can see that the `grammarDef` rule specifies a valid ANTLR3 grammar as follows: `'grammar' id ';' optionsSpec? tokensSpec? attrScope* action* rule+ EOF` (the order which I mentioned)

Comment: The v3 grammar: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v3/blob/master/Antlrv3/ANTLRv3.g